# adding multiple markers dynamically in google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am now using .text() to get latng from the html.

```
<div class="latlng"> -33.91722, 151.23064</div>
<div class="latlng"> -32.81620, 151.11313</div>
```

So, i am using $(latlng).text() to fetch the data into the jquery.

```
var geo = $(latlng).text();
latitude = parseFloat(geo);
longitudeP = geocoder.replace(latitude+',','');
longitude = parseFloat(longitudeP);
```

I am using this code under each function to get all of the coordinates with having the same class. 
No, how do i add multiple markers dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using the marker object and the latitude and longitude variables you have:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
});
```

I have created a JSFiddle to demonstrate this for you. I had to make some slight modifications to handle things like trailing 0s and whitespace. Note that I have redacted my API from this fiddle for security. Please put your own API key in the fiddle for it to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/8bfmc6oo/

I hope this helps!